# Uber Deep link for Web Mobile dropoff coordinates doesn't work

Tags: uber-api

I'm linking to a url like this but is not getting the destination (dropoff coordinates):

https://m.uber.com/?action=pickup&setpickup=my_locatio&client_id=XXXXXXX&dropoff_latitude=-33.4517787&dropoff_longitude=-70.60097997000003

When m.uber.com open only ask for the pickup location, but does not receive the destination coordinates.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set clientId before pickup point.

String uri ="uber://?client_id="+clientId+"&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=xxxxxx&pickup[longitude]=xxxxxx&pickup[nickname]=Your Current Loaction&dropoff[latitude]=xxxxx&dropoff[longitude]=xxxxxx&dropoff[nickname]=destination";